# How to pass xml contents as parameter while testing Rest service in SOAPUI

Tags: rest, soapui

I want to pass XML contents as a parameter while testing Rest service in SOAPUI.

I have given an XML payload inside mediaType application/xml or application/json.
But I am getting this error:

> Message: The specified method is not allowed against this resource.

I have also given CDATA, but it is also not working. Can anybody please help?

Comment: Accept user define class object as a parameter and try to test using SOAP UI. You need to pass the value in form of XML.

Comment: Can you show a shot of the request? Do you mean to say that entire xml has to be set as request for a step?

Comment: Entire XML has to be set as request.

Comment: <Envelope>
 <Body>
  <Details>
   <Id>123<Id>
   <EmpId>567</EmpId>
   <ServiceType>Testing</ServiceType>
  </Details>
 </Body>
</Envelope>  this is the sample xml.

Comment: namespace i have correctly mentioned in my xml also.

Comment: Can you show the test case and its steps?